# C++ constructor call with boost::filesystem::path as argument - nothing happening

Tags: c++, constructor

I have a problem that is puzzling me, something is missing from my c++ understanding.

I'm trying to construct an object with a boost::filesystem::path (which itself is constructed from a basic_string) I thought I could save a line of code by doing the construction of the boost path on the same line as I construct my object.

See the example below:

One thing that i don't understand is that, although it doesn't work, I also get no errors. i.e. nothing seems to happen. Why would that be?

```
class Test {
 public:
    Test(boost::filesystem::path in) {
        std::cout << "Succesful construction" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::string str("asdf.txt");
    boost::filesystem::path p(str);
    Test test1(boost::filesystem::path(str));  // Nothing at all happens, but no error
    Test test2(p);  // "Succesful construction"
}
```

Comment: Compile with warning: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/03cb344a458af9c6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is C++'s so-called "most vexing parse." The problem you're running into is that this:

```
Test test1(boost::filesystem::path(str));
```

is a declaration for a function named `test1` that returns a `Test` and takes one argument of type `boost::filesystem::path` named `str`. The parentheses around `str` are parsed as superfluous, so the line is interpreted as equivalent to:

```
Test test1(boost::filesystem::path str);
```

---

If you're compiling with C++11, you can replace the outer parentheses with braces:

```
Test test1{boost::filesystem::path(str)};
```

Pre-C++11, you can use an extra set of parentheses:

```
Test test1((boost::filesystem::path(str)));
```